# Buffers not working in vim

Tags: vim, runtime-error, buffer, vi

My buffers are not working for some reason. When I click <leader>b it says

> Not an editor command: Buffers

This is my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" General
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'

" User Interface
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'JarrodCTaylor/vim-256-color-schemes'
Plugin 'JarrodCTaylor/vim-reflection'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'

" Programming
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'

" Languages
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'


" all plugins must be above this line!!

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype  plugin indent on   " required

" non-plugin stuff after this line!!

" Map leader to ,
let mapleader=','

set t_Co=256
syntax on

set nobackup                           " Don't constantly write backup files
set noswapfile                         " Ain't nobody got time for swap files
set noerrorbells                       " Don't beep
set nowrap                             " Do not wrap lines
set shiftwidth=4                       " Number of spaces to use for each step of indent
set showcmd                            " Display incomplete commands in the bottom line of the screen
set tabstop=4                          " Number of spaces that a <Tab> counts for
set undolevels=1000                    " Never can be too careful when it comes to undoing
set hidden                             " Don't unload the buffer when we switch between them. Saves undo history
set visualbell                         " Visual bell instead of beeping
set wildmenu                           " Command-line completion in an enhanced mode
set shell=bash                         " Required to let zsh know how to run things on the command line
set ttimeoutlen=50                     " Fix delay when escaping from insert with Esc
set noshowmode                         " Hide the default mode text (e.g. -- INSERT -- below the statusline)
set showbreak=↪\
set synmaxcol=256
set scrolloff=3
set clipboard=unnamed
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.json set ft=javascript

" Status line / visual configuration

syntax enable
set t_Co=256
set t_ut=
hi clear
hi String ctermfg=81 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5fd7ff guibg=NONE gui=NONE
hi CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=white

set laststatus=2                                    " Make the second to last line of vim our status line
let g:airline_theme='understated'                   " Use the custom theme I wrote
let g:airline_left_sep=''                           " No separator as they seem to look funky
let g:airline_right_sep=''                          " No separator as they seem to look funky
let g:airline#extensions#branch#enabled = 0         " Do not show the git branch in the status line
let g:airline#extensions#syntastic#enabled = 1      " Do show syntastic warnings in the status line
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_buffers = 0   " Do not list buffers in the status line
let g:airline_section_x = ''                        " Do not list the filetype or virtualenv in the status line
let g:airline_section_y = '[R%04l,C%04v] [LEN=%L]'  " Replace file encoding and file format info with file position
let g:airline_section_z = ''                        " Do not show the default file position info
let g:airline#extensions#virtualenv#enabled = 0
autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :.cc<CR>
autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> o :.cc<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>W :%s/\s\+$//<CR>:let @/=''<CR>
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1                   " check for errors when file is loaded
let g:syntastic_loc_list_height=5                 " the height of the error list defaults to 10
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['flake8']      " sets flake8 as the default for checking python files
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']  " sets jshint as our javascript linter
let g:syntastic_filetype_map = { 'handlebars.html': 'handlebars' }
let g:syntastic_mode_map={ 'mode': 'active',
                     \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                     \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html', 'handlebars'] }

set tags=./.ctags,.ctags;
let g:NERDTreeMapJumpNextSibling = ''
let g:NERDTreeMapJumpPrevSibling = ''
let g:gundo_preview_bottom = 1
let g:markdown_fold_style = 'nested'
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['python', 'sh', 'vim', 'javascript', 'html', 'css', 'c', 'sql']
let g:indent_guides_start_level = 2
let g:indent_guides_guide_size = 1
let g:indent_guides_exclude_filetypes = ['help', 'nerdtree']
let g:indent_guides_auto_colors = 0
autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesOdd  ctermbg=238
autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesEven ctermbg=249

function! s:DeleteBuffer()
    let line = getline('.')
    let bufid = line =~ '\[\d\+\*No Name\]$' ? str2nr(matchstr(line, '\d\+'))
        \ : fnamemodify(line[2:], ':p')
    exec "bd" bufid
    exec "norm \<F5>"
endfunction
" NERDTree configuration
let g:NERDTreeChDirMode=2
let g:NERDTreeIgnore=['\.rbc$', '\~$', '\.pyc$', '\.db$', '\.sqlite$', '__pycache__']
let g:NERDTreeSortOrder=['^__\.py$', '\/$', '*', '\.swp$', '\.bak$', '\~$']
let g:NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_focus_on_files=1
let g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTabSilent = '<RightMouse>'
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 50
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.pyc,*.db,*.sqlite
nnoremap <silent> <F2> :NERDTreeFind<CR>
nmap <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" buffer configuration
nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :Buffers<CR>
" close buffer

nnoremap <leader>c :bd<CR>
```

Can someone tell me if I missed something? I will also accept tips on upgrading my vimrc file so feel free to give any tips :) But I mainly want to fix this problem. So please tell me what I should remove or add to get this working again. It was working before. This really appeared suddenly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a typo, see `:h buffers`
Please change following line (lowercase the `B` in `:Buffers`)

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :Buffers<CR>
```

to

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :buffers<CR>
```